# Objective c memory leak when using uisegmentcontrol to switch views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a memory leak that I do not understand. I am switching views with a segmentcontrol like this:

```
- (void)didChangeSegmentControl:(UISegmentedControl *)control {
    if (self.activeViewController) {
        [self.activeViewController viewWillDisappear:NO];
        [self.activeViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.activeViewController viewDidDisappear:NO];
    }

    self.activeViewController = [self.segmentedViewControllers objectAtIndex:control.selectedSegmentIndex];


    [self.activeViewController viewWillAppear:NO];
    [self.containerView addSubview:self.activeViewController.view];//Here is the memory leak
    [self.activeViewController viewDidAppear:NO];

    [self BuildBottomBarButtons];   

}
```

I leak appears in Instruments and I do not have any idea why...
Thanks!!!

Edit:
The "BuildBottomBarButtons":

```
-(void) BuildBottomBarButtons{


    //create toolbar using new
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [UIToolbar new];   
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;  
    [toolbar sizeToFit];    
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 330, 320, 50);

    //Add buttons       
    UIBarButtonItem *systemItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction                                                                                  target:self                                                                                     action:@selector(shareClicked)];

    UIBarButtonItem *systemItem2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scroll left.PNG"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(upClicked)];

    UIBarButtonItem *systemItem3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scroll right.PNG"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(downClicked)];

    //Use this to put space in between your toolbox buttons 
    UIBarButtonItem *fixItem50 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace   target:nil      action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *fixItem70 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace   target:nil      action:nil];
    fixItem50.width = 50;
    fixItem70.width = 64;
    //Add buttons to the array      
    NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: systemItem1, fixItem70, systemItem2, fixItem50,systemItem3, nil];

    //release buttons   
    [systemItem1 release];  
    [systemItem2 release];  
    [systemItem3 release];  
    [fixItem70 release];
    [fixItem50 release];

    //add array of buttons to toolbar
    [toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];

    [self.containerView addSubview:toolbar];
    [toolbar release];
}
```

And the "self.segmentedViewControllers" init method is:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)segmentedViewControllerContent {
    JobGeneralDetailsController * controller1 = [[JobGeneralDetailsController alloc] initWithSelectedRowID:selectedRowID andWithJobBoardID:jobBoardId andWithJobDetails:jobDetails];
    [controller1 setViewType:jobDetailsViewType];
    //initWithParentViewController:self];
    JobMapDetailsController * controller2 = [[JobMapDetailsController alloc] initWithJobDetails:jobDetails];//[[AustraliaViewController alloc] initWithParentViewController:self];

    [controller1 setJobMapDetailsController: controller2];


    JobReviewsController *controller3 = [[JobReviewsController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    [controller3 setJobDetails:jobDetails];
    [controller3 setViewType:jobDetailsViewType];

    [controller1 setJobReviewsController: controller3];

    NSMutableArray * controllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:controller1, controller2, controller3,nil];

    [controller1 release];
    [controller2 release];
    [controller3 release];

    return controllers;
}
```

[image]

Comment: The leak is not in the code you provided, but is perhaps triggered by something in this code. Can you show us the `BuildBottomBarButtons` method? Also, methods should start with a lowercase letter, even for class methods. The only exception to this rule is for acronyms, such as `-[NSString UTF8String]`

Comment: In instruments, it is possible to see the line where the leak is probably at. Did you see it? which line is it pointing to?

Comment: The line leaking is:[self.containerView addSubview:self.activeViewController.view];

Answer (score 0):

The only line I could point to is [self BuildBottomBarButtons];

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code the only problem I can see is in the [self BuildBottomBarButtons]

It looks like you are adding the toolbar to the container view everytime you switch view controllers.

What type of object does Instruments say is leaking, is it possible to see a screen shot of your instruments screen showing the leaked objects?

Comment: I removed the line of "BuildBottomBarButtons" and the leak is still here. Now it has another line (in the same leak). In viewDidLoad I cal "BindViews" which has the following leak: `companyName.text = [jobDetails objectForKey:@"CompanyName"];`

Comment: Is it possible to see a screen of the list of leaked blocks so we can see the type of objects been leaked.  Looking at your code I can't really see anything wrong.   Only thing I can think of suggesting is check the code in your view controllers.  Are you doing anything in the viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear methods on your view controllers?